# Update field in unrelated table by spanning relationships using Django ORM

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I am using Django 3.0.4. I have 6 tables (Vehicle, Tracker, Driver, Contract, Account and Invoice). There are Many Invoices for each Account(1-M). A single Account is opened for every single Contract(1-1). Each Contract is comprised of a Driver and a Vehicle and Driver-Vehicle combination can have only 1 Contract. Each Vehicle is fitted with a single Tracker(1-1). I intend to check the status of the Invoice(I have done this already) and navigating from this particular record of Invoice I need to find the particular Vehicle inorder to update the status of the Tracker. Tracker has no relation to Invoice and select_related does not seem to work. Your assistance is appreciated.

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
registration = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique = True)
make = models.CharField(max_length=16)
model = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Tracker(models.Model):
vehicle = models.OneToOneField('Vehicle', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
msisdn = models.PositiveIntegerField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Driver(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Contract(models.Model):
vehicle = models.ForeignKey('Vehicle', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
driver = models.ForeignKey('Driver', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

class Account(models.Model):
contract = models.OneToOneField('Contract', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
weekly_amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
weeks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
paid_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Invoice(models.Model):
account = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=INVOICE_STATUS, default=UNPAID)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the normal Django lookups? Something like ```invoice.account.contract.vehicle.tracker``` should give you the appropriate ```Tracker```.

Comment: This has done the trick. Thanks for offering that advise.
tracker = Tracker.objects.get(vehicle__contract__account__invoice = invoice.id)